# Fill a range of unmerged cells

Tags: excel

In Excel, how do I fill a range of cells without merging them?

For example, given
[image]

I can merge the 4 cells and then apply a fill to the range, as in
[image]

However only the content of one cell is displayed. If I avoid merging, gradient filling is applied to the cells, not the range
[image]

What I want is to keep the cells separated and apply a filling to the range.

I know that I can achieve this with a rectangular shape
[image]
but this complicates editing as shapes can only be in front (and not behind) cells.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: What is the use case for this requirment?

Comment: @Ike The ensemble of 4 cells describes a unique entity, which is visually characterized by a gradient pattern